# Probability, set union, set intersection

Tags: probability

An arbitrary object has a round shape with probability
1/3. Furthermore, we know that round objects have a red color with a probability of 1/2, while red
objects have a round shape with a probability of 3/4.

a) Calculate the probability that an object is both red and round

I got: $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)=3/4 \cdot 1/2 = 3/8$

b) Calculate the probability that an object has a red color but not a round shape.

I got: $P(A\cap B^*)=3/4 \cdot 2/3=1/2$

Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: Those two properties are not independent.  Just draw a Venn Diagram and use the given information to compute the relevant probabilities.

Comment: Roundness and redness are not independent, so you cannot use the product form (which assumes independence). Rather, construct a Venn diagram, and find out how to assign probabilities to the three regions ($A \setminus B, A \cap B, B \setminus A$) such that the conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Oh I forgot that they are NOT independent. So for a), it becomes $P(A \cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cup B)=1/2+1/3 - 1/4=0.583$?

Comment: Those are not the values you were given.  Letting $A$ be the event of redness, and $B$ the event of roundness, then "An arbitrary object has a round shape with probability 1/3," says $\mathsf P(B)=1/3$, "round objects have a red color with a probability of 1/2," says $\mathsf P(A\mid B)=1/2$, and "red objects have a round shape with a probability of 3/4" says $\mathsf P(B\mid A)=3/4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ denote the event that the object is round.

Let $B$ denote the event that the object is red.

Part A.

$p(A \cap B) = p(A) \times p(B|A) = (1/3) \times (1/2) = (1/6).$

It is true that you are also given that $p(A|B) = (3/4)$.

However, this fact is useless in part A, because $p(B)$ is not given.

---

Part B is tricky.

$p(B|A) \times p(A) = (1/6) = p(A|B) \times p(B).$ 
Since $p(A|B) = (3/4)$, you have that

$\displaystyle p(B) = \frac{(1/6)}{(3/4)} = \frac{2}{9}.$

Further, since $p(A|B) = (3/4)$ 
you must have that $p(\neg A | B) = (1/4).$

Therefore, $~\displaystyle p(\neg A, B) = p(B) \times p(\neg A|B) = \frac{2}{9} \times \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{18}.$

**Edit**
$p(\neg A, B)$ may also be calculated as  
$\displaystyle p(B) - p(A, B) = \frac{2}{9} - \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{18}.$

**Edit**
An alternative (somewhat sophisticated) shortcut for part B is:

- $p(A|B) = (3/4)$ and $p(A,B) = (1/6).$
- Therefore, since $p(\neg A | B) = (1/4)$, 
  which is $(1/3)$ the size of $p(A|B)$, 
  you must have that 
  $p(\neg A,B)$ is $(1/3)$ the size of $p(A,B).$ 
  Therefore, $p(\neg A,B) = (1/3) \times (1/6).$

Answer (score 1):

**First** determine what the information given *actually* says.  You are given one marginal and two conditional probabilities.

Letting $A$ be the event of redness, and $B$ the event of roundness, then "An arbitrary object has a round shape with probability 1/3," says $\mathsf P(B)=1/3$, "round objects have a red color with a probability of 1/2," says $\mathsf P(A\mid B)=1/2$, and "red objects have a round shape with a probability of 3/4" says $\mathsf P(B\mid A)=3/4$.

**Now** use the *definition of conditional probability*, to find $\mathsf P(A\cap B)$ and $\mathsf P(A)$, and use those to find $\mathsf P(A\cap B^{\small\complement})$